# How to rebuild a nano package so that after it becomes possible to launch the nano editor from any directory, by entering the command newnano?

Tags: linux, rpm, nano

While I've been doing my Linux project, I've faced a problem with rebuilding the nano package so that after it is installed by the package manager, it becomes possible to launch the nano editor from any directory, by entering the command newnano. How can it be solved specifically using **rpmrebuild** package? Am I supposed to change nano manifest?

Comment: What does this have to do with Bash?

Comment: I'm asked to implement it in bash

Comment: what prevents nano from being launched now?

Comment: nothing, but this exact task I'm supposed to implement in my project :)

Comment: actually, I should rebuild nano package so that nano would launch using newnano. variant of using allias does not work here

Answer (score 0):

after installing rmprebuild, you should perform

```
    rpmrebuild -enp ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/newnano-2.9.8-1.el1.x86_64.rpm
```

than in the manifest

```
    mv /usr/bin/nano /usr/bin/newnano
```

than

```
    yum remove nano
    rpm -i /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64x/newnano-2.9.8-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!